# How to resize navbar in bootstrap IE Only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with dipslaying the header on my website in IE. On Chrome, FF and Opera it works as expected. IE is the exception. The width is corrupted.

Here is the website: http://tinyurl.com/obr38o3

I tried to add the IE specific stylesheet to the html in the head section right after the other css files.

```
<!--[if lt IE]>
<link href="css/ie.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
<!-- end CSS -->
```

But it seems not to work.

I have tried different approaches: html codes, css codes, but to no avail.

Could you help me to come up with solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your problem conflict css classes. Do you try **!important**

.example{
   height:100px !important
}

Answer (score 0):

Target IE5  and HIGHER

```
[if gt IE 5]
```

or

Target everything EXCEPT IE

```
[if !IE]
```